# What do Samsungs "GN/RSBD", "CN/RSBS", "CN/RSSS" for external devices mean?

Tags: optical-drive, external-drive

I am currently looking for external dvd devices and found three from Samsung which look almost identical:

- Samsung SE-218CN/RSSS
- Samsung SE-218CN/RSBS
- Samsung SE-218GN/RSBD

I guess the second last letter means either "sillver" or "black", but do the other letters have a meaning? Besides the look, are there other differences between those 3 models?

Comment: @Mokubai: Why did you remove the [tag:samsung] tag?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between these models is the `access time`.

> The access time for an optical drive is measured the same way as for PC hard disk drives. In other words, the access time is the delay between the drive receiving the command to read and its actual first reading of a bit of data. Access rates quoted by many manufacturers are an average taken by calculating a series of random reads from a disc.

Access Times:

**SE-218CN** - CD-ROM 150 ms, DVD-ROM 150 ms. For this model, RSSS and RSBS denote color. SS = silver, BS = black

**SE-218GN/RSBD** - CD-ROM 210ms, DVD-ROM 220ms